# Matplotlib ion is not working in ubuntu terminal

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need a non blocking interactive matplotlib plot. But when I use `ion` PLot is not getting displayed. It suddenly getting closed.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.ion() 
plt.plot([1.4, 2.5]) 
print("***********")
```

Is there any solution to make it run from terminal

Environment Spec

> Ubuntu - 18.04
> Matplotlib - 3.3.2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.ion() 
plt.plot([1.4, 2.5]) 
print("***********")
plt.show(block=True) #this keeps the graph result shown. Close it manually
```

Comment: Actually I want a non blocking plot

Answer (score 0):

```
from terminalplot import plot
```

Get size of current terminal window:

```
from terminalplot import get_terminal_size
get_terminal_size()
```

#I hope this works for you. You can try different visualizations instead of using ion (). I guess I can only help that much.